# Dialog box not resolving on click in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm having a problem where when I click on submit in a dialog box the resolve event on the dialog box is supposed to call a function. The dialog closes when the button is click but the api function is never called (as seen from dev tools). If I stop the tests and manually do the action in the cypress browser it will work call the function. I'm not sure why the manual click is acting different than the test runners click?

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes you need a hard ms wait(should be avoided)...**
You may have a wait issue. Add a `cy.wait(1000)` 1000ms hard wait and see if that fixes it. If it does, you will want to identify what hasn't loaded fully when the button is pressed. While hard waits should be strongly avoided, I find myself using them sparingly with the smallest amount of milliseconds(x2 for safety) that I can get by with. Animations are one such example that comes to mind.

**Make sure all subscriptions are ready**
I am working on a meteor app that using websockets(tricker to wait on than xhr events). I call a method that returns true/false for all subscriptions. This helps wait for any events that cypress doesn't see in the network layer. Ask your devs if there is a method in your application that returns true/false depending on the ready state of the application.

**Review for Race condition**
This could be a legitimate race condition. I would review it with the devs just in case.